Doxygen: Arithmetic in macro expansion
Doxygen configuration
ENABLE_PREPROCESSING   = YES
MACRO_EXPANSION        = YES
EXPAND_ONLY_PREDEF     = NO

My code
#define a 10
#define b 5
#define length a + b

uint8_t buffer[length];

The generated output for the variable is uint8_t buffer[10+5];. Is it possible to make it as uint8_t buffer[15];?

Doxygen is not a compiler and does not execute code / perform arithmetic operations. So this is not possible.
